# Generate a random number between range (-0.5 , 0.5) in C

Tags: c, random

Consider the following C program :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {

        static float a = 0;
        a = (rand() % 2001 - 1000) / 2.e3;
        printf("%.4f ", a);
    }
}
```

This will successfully generate then print a list of random number between **-0.5 to 0.5**. For example :

```
./main.out
-0.2475 -0.3640 -0.3945 0.2995 0.0460 0.2230 -0.0340 0.1630 -0.2275 -0.3450 0.3560 -0.4335 -0.0025 -0.2980 -0.0505 -0.1815 0.3115 -0.4465 -0.1325 -0.2340
```

I checked the Precedence of Operators and still don't understand how the expression `(rand()%2001 - 1000)/2.e3` works.

(*especially where does the **negative sign** comes from*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze the expression `(rand() % 2001 - 1000) / 2.e3`:

- the `rand()` function defined in `<stdlib.h>` returns a pseudo random integer of type `int` in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX` inclusively. `RAND_MAX` is a constant also defined in `<stdlib.h>` whose value is at least `32767`.
- `rand() % 2001` computes the remainder of the division by `2001`. Since `rand()` is positive, the result is a pseudo random number in the range `0` to `2000` inclusive, with a small bias caused by `2001` not dividing `RAND_MAX` evenly.
- `rand() % 2001 - 1000` is evaluated as `(rand() % 2001) - 1000`, the range of the result is shifted by 1000 toward the negatives, namely between `-1000` and `1000` inclusively.
- to evaluate `(rand() % 2001 - 1000) / 2.e3`, the value obtained from the previous steps is converted to type `double` and divided by `2.e3`, which would be more readable as `2000.0`. Hence the result is a floating point value of type `double` with 2001 possible distinct values between `-0.5` and `0.5` inclusively.
- `a = (rand() % 2001 - 1000) / 2.e3;` converts this `double` value to `float`, the type of `a`. The `float` value will be implicitly converted back to type `double` when passed to `printf`, this conversion does not produce exactly the same number in many cases.
- note that there is no reason to define `a` as a `static` variable.

Here is an alternative implementation that produces more distinct values in the same inclusive range with a slightly less biased distribution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        double a = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX - 0.5;
        printf("%f ", a);
    }
    printf("%\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your answer definitely helped a lot. But when I directly copied your code into my environment and then tested a couple of times, I found theses results are all negative numbers. (The expected range is -1 to 1).

Comment: @MosesChan: My mistake! sorry about that, the adjustment must be `-0.5`, not `-1.0`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  a = (rand() % 2001 - 1000) / 2.e3;
> ```

`rand()` is evaluated first

```
    a = (rand() % 2001 - 1000) / 2.e3;
         ^^^^^^ int between `0` and `RAND_MAX` inclusive
```

Then the modulus operator generates a value between `0` and `2000`.

```
    a = ([0 .. 2000] - 1000) / 2.e3;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^ int
```

Then that value has `1000` subtracted, becoming a value between `-1000` and `1000`

```
    a = ([-1000 .. 1000]) / 2.e3;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ int
```

Then, divided by `2000.0` (or `2.e3`) generates a `double` between `-0.5` and `0.5`

```
    a = [-0.5 .. 0.5];
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ double
```